# UICollectionView multiple cells selected at same time

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and a `UICollectionViewCell` as subclass, in this cell i have buttons and labels created from XiB, when i click any `UIButton` in **cell** i'm changing the BG image of `UILabel` in that cell, then i Scroll the `UICollectionViewCell` **i see same thing was happened of some other cell.** How can i solve this???

This is how i'm calling custom class..

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

     NMCFAIPadWishListCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setWishList:[[self wishListData] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] delegate:self];

     return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code Tell me its working or not

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NMCFAIPadWishListCell *cell = (NMCFAIPadWishListCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageCategory.image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedeimagename.png"]
 ];
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NMCFAIPadWishListCell *cell = (NMCFAIPadWishListCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.imageCategory.image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselectedeimagename.png"]
 ];

}
```